# Problem with .push with Asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

The Problem is with the uplines.push.
I always get an empty uplines array so the last part of the code doesn't run. The promises resolve later and I get the correct data. May I know how to go about doing it the correct way?

```
 const getAllUplines = async () => {
uplines = [];
const findUser = async (userFid) => {
  const userDoc = await firestore.collection("users").doc(userFid).get();
  if (userDoc.exists) {
    const user = { ...userDoc.data(), id: userDoc.id };
    console.log(user);
    uplines.push(user);
    if (user.immediateUplineFid) {
      findUser(user.immediateUplineFid); //self looping
    }
  } else {
    console.log("No User Found");
    return null;
  }
};

sale.rens.forEach(async (ren) => {
  findUser(ren.userFid);
});
console.log(uplines);
return uplines;


};



let uplines = await getAllUplines();
  console.log(uplines);

  uplines = uplines.filter(
    (v, i) => uplines.findIndex((index) => index === v) === i
  ); //remove duplicates

  uplines.forEach((user) => {
    if (user.chatId) {
      sendTelegramMessage(user.chatId, saleToDisplay, currentUser.displayName);
      console.log("Telegram Message Sent to " + user.displayName);
    } else {
      console.log(user.displayName + " has no chatId");
    }
  });
```

Comment: I have a few questions. All of the code that you posted above. Is it inside of another asynchronous function? You can't use the `await` keyword at `let uplines = await getAllUplines()` unless the entire snippet you posted above is inside of an async function. Also, when you say "I always get an empty uplines array" which line of the code are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you have missed out while implementing the async call, which are explained in the inline comments in the code snippet.

A short explanation for what happened in your code is that in the line `sale.rens.forEach` you are passing an async function in the argument, which does not make any difference to the function forEach, it will execute it without waiting for it to complete.

Therefore in my answer I am using `Promise.all` to wait for all the async function calls to complete before returning the result.

```js
// This is wrapped in an immediately executed async function because await in root is not supported here
(async () => {
  const mockGetData = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  const sale = {
    rens: [
      { userFid: 1 },
      { userFid: 2 },
      { userFid: 3 }
    ]
  };
  
  const getAllUplines = async () => {
    const uplines = [];
    const findUser = async (userFid) => {
      // Simulating an async function call
      const userDoc = await mockGetData();
      console.log("User data received");
      uplines.push(`User ${userFid}`);
    };

    const promises = [];
    sale.rens.forEach(ren => {  // This function in foreach does not have to be declared as async
      // The function findUser is an async function, which returns a promise, so we have to keep track of all the promises returned to be used later
      promises.push(findUser(ren.userFid));
    });
    await Promise.all(promises);
    return uplines;
  };

  let uplines = await getAllUplines();
  console.log(uplines);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the results of `getAllUplines()` properly, you need to add `await` to all async functions called in `getAllUplines()`.

```
const getAllUplines = async () => {
    uplines = [];
    const findUser = async (userFid) => {
        const userDoc = await firestore.collection("users").doc(userFid).get();
        if (userDoc.exists) {
            const user = { ...userDoc.data(), id: userDoc.id };
            console.log(user);
            uplines.push(user);
            if (user.immediateUplineFid) {
                await findUser(user.immediateUplineFid); //self looping
            }
        } else {
            console.log("No User Found");
            return null;
        }
    };

    sale.rens.forEach(async (ren) => {
        await findUser(ren.userFid);
    });
    console.log(uplines);
    return uplines;
};
```

Comment: If you have tried to run your code you will find it does not work as expected.